# Como migrar meu website para RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, módulo-ecmascript, amd

Atualmente eu concateno todos os meus javascripts com grunt mando o arquivo minificado para a página, mas eu sei que uma melhor prática é usar o RequireJS para mudularizar tudo, mas não sei como migrar meus arquivos Javascript de "normais" para "módulos". :/

Comment: O que tens no servidor? Node.js ou PHP? Podias fazer a transição para sintaxe ES6 sem ter de passar por RequireJS que vai provavelmente desaparecer.

Comment: Atualmente tenho PHP, mas tbm estou migrando para o NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

Você precisará também do [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js), que é a ferramenta que permite executar o RequireJS de dentro do node.js. Para gerar um único arquivo `main.js` contendo todos seus arquivos JavaScript você roda o comando abaixo:

```
node r.js -o build.js
```

*Adaptado da resposta em inglês https://stackoverflow.com/a/14338363/1639385*